# python curses remote debugging pdevd error in setupterm

Tags: python, debugging, ncurses, curses, python-curses

Is it possible to debug a curse program remotely in PyCharm? How to set it up?

I followed the PyCharm 4.0.8 instruction, added this to the "`EXAMPLE.py`" from "`npyscreen-4.8.7`".

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=8899, stdoutToServer=False, stderrToServer=True)
```

And always it runs into an error in "`setupterm`":

```
$ PYTHONPATH=~/bin/pycharm-debug.egg python EXAMPLE.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EXAMPLE.py", line 34, in <module>
    App.run()
  File "/home/.../npyscreen-4.8.7/npyscreen/apNPSApplication.py", line 30, in run
    return npyssafewrapper.wrapper(self.__remove_argument_call_main)
  File "/home/.../npyscreen-4.8.7/npyscreen/npyssafewrapper.py", line 41, in wrapper
    wrapper_no_fork(call_function)
  File "/home/.../npyscreen-4.8.7/npyscreen/npyssafewrapper.py", line 83, in wrapper_no_fork
    _SCREEN = curses.initscr()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
    fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

---

The problem is that pydevd changed environment "TERM" from "xterm" to "emacs". This can be verified by a little test program.

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=8899, stdoutToServer=False, stderrToServer=True)
import os as _os
import sys as _sys
import curses
print " my term: ", _os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"), "\n"
print " my fd:   ", _sys.__stdout__.fileno(), "\n"
print "\n  ok  1  \n"
curses.setupterm(term=_os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"),
#curses.setupterm(term='xterm',
                fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
print "\n  ok  2  \n"
```

- If removing the two lines with "`pdevd`", the program succeeds. The "`TERM`" it prints out is "`xterm`".
- If change the 1st argument to "`setupterm`" into "`term='xterm'`", even with "`pydevd`" it succeeds.

I guess the question is how to have "`pydevd`" setup the correct "`TERM`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This various hints pointing out the hardcoded setting of the TERM in pydevd led me to this sequence, which works for me:

```
#
# From the instructions in the PyCharm remote debug setup screen,
# add this to your code before curses is initialised.
#
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=8899)
#
# And then to fixup the broken setting in pydevd...
#
os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm'
```

Comment: This looks nice however not verified by me though I set this answer as accepted. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

While one of the answer could be this: Change `/usr/lib/python2.6/curses/__init__.py` to force TERM like:

```
def initscr():
    import _curses, curses
    # we call setupterm() here because it raises an error
    # instead of calling exit() in error cases.
    _os.environ['TERM'] = 'xterm' ##hack force 'xterm' for pydevd debugging.
    setupterm(term=_os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"),
              fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
    stdscr = _curses.initscr()
    for key, value in _curses.__dict__.items():
        if key[0:4] == 'ACS_' or key in ('LINES', 'COLS'):
            setattr(curses, key, value)

    return stdscr
```

The original source that changed "`TERM`" is here:

```
$ head plugins/org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356/pysrc/pydev_ipython_console.py 
import sys
from pydev_console_utils import BaseInterpreterInterface

import os

os.environ['TERM'] = 'emacs' #to use proper page_more() for paging


# Uncomment to force PyDev standard shell.
# raise ImportError()
```

Comment: Setting `TERM` to "emacs" is probably incorrect unless one happens to be running within the emacs program.

Comment: Actually it is the IDE console needs to set it to emacs. Both PyCharm and Eclipse do.

Comment: That's likely due to rote copying.  ncurses doesn't provide an entry named "emacs" (and [Emacs documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Termcap_002fTerminfo-entries-for-Emacs.html) doesn't assume one is installed).  That was made obsolete long ago by the "eterm" entry.